# Get file size before upload on Node.js

Tags: node.js, node.js-stream

On Node.js, how i can get the file size ?

```
const { createReadStream, filename, ...rest } = await file;
```

`...rest` does not contain this information :/ And i can't use `statSync` because my file isn't created yet, i'm on before state.

> The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or
> URL. Received an instance of ReadStream

Comment: It depends on where you are reading the file from. What, exactly, is `file`? How did you get that value in the first place?

Comment: Hi Quentin ! `file` is `ReadStream` (i've updated my first post)

Comment: And where does it come from?

Comment: Please add the full error stack(it looks like [this](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errorstack) ), there's likely exact line number where the error comes from. You are passing a ReadStream into a function which does not expect it. Show the relevant code.